# IE Enhanced Security Configuration в WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

Можно ли через класс WebBrowser определить включена ли защита IE Enhanced Security Configuration?

Кейс: В десктопном приложении отрисовка происходит в html. В случае включенной защиты у IE, выполнение скриптов на странице приведет к ошибке:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800700AA): The requested resource is in use. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700AA).`

Хочется сразу понять, что защита включена и выдать пользователю сообщение о необходимости изменения настроек без выпадения кучи таких ошибок.

Comment: Возможно есть проще способ, типа залезть в реестр, и там увидеть эту настройку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если опираться на решения, предложенные [здесь](https://techontip.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/registry-key-to-disalbe-internet-explorer-enhenced-security/) и [здесь](https://www.serverknowledge.net/group-policy/disable-ie-esc-gpo/), то получается вот такая функция проверки:

```
// using Microsoft.Win32;
// using System.Security.AccessControl;
static bool IsIeEnhancedSecurityEnabled()
{
    var keyNames = new [] {
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}",
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    };

    foreach (var keyName in keyNames) {
        using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName,
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, RegistryRights.ReadKey))
        {
            if (key != null) {
                var value = key.GetValue("IsInstalled") as int?;
                if (value == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Проверял на Windows Server 2008 R2, для других версий нет возможности протестировать.